# useContext() is terminated without any error message

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

In the code snip below, execution never reaches to useNavigate() line. It terminates at useContext() line without any error message. However, I managed to use useContext at another place without any issue. That makes me to think problem is related with, where and how I call logOut and relatedly useContext.

```
import AuthContext from '../store/auth-context';
import { useState, useRef, useContext } from 'react';

export default function LogOut()  {
    const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigator = useNavigate();
    
    authCtx.logout();
    // optional: redirect the user
    navigator('/dbsection');
  
    return;
  };
```

The place where LogOut is called:

```
import logOut from '../components/logOut.js';

        <NavBtn>
          <NavBtnLink to='/formLogIn'>Log In</NavBtnLink>
          <NavBtnLink to='/dbsection' onClick={logOut}>Log Out</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      </Nav>
```

I tried to create an instance from useContext() hook. I wanted to call a function of related context but I couldn't create the instance.

Comment: How do you know it terminates there?

Comment: In debugger, i put breakpoint to both of these lines. Program comes to useContext(AuthContext); line, it steps into default react codes. and when i click continue, it doesnt stop at the break point of useNavigate(); line. I think for some reason it doesnt step out from default react.js codes. But I couldnt trace until the point it stopped, because so many codes are executed inside of useContext.

Comment: <Context.Consumer> </Context.Consumer> approach made it working but i still wonder, what was wrong with useContext hook

Comment: I realized one thing, eror something like "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" appears on console for less than a second and then disappears. I am not sure if the reason of that error is related with useContext issue

Comment: Hooka can only be used in the component body. You can't use hook in a handler

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is that useContext hook is called/triggered via onClick handle. I dont know why but for some reason, React doesnt allow this. I just moved content of external 'logOut' function into the component where I call logOut, and useContext worked as well.
Why React doesnt allow useContext hook, or maybe all hooks to be called through onClick handle, thats still a question for me.

Comment: It is a key aspect of React hooks that they are only allowed in React function components. They do not work in an arbitrary function. And further restrictions apply. It's not related to `onClick()`.